# How to use KDE partition manager to make linux partition larger

Tags: partitioning

My main Ubuntu 18 partition is getting crowded.  I wanted to take some of the extra space from the FAT partition.  I opened both KDE partition manager and the DISK utility because the partition manager doesn't really tell me what's what.  ON the disk utility it had sd8 as the Ubuntu system.  So, I shrunk a different partition and removed a partition that said it was free space but I couldn't see how to enlarge my Linux partition.  But then, I look at the Disk utility and it no longer has a linux system partition.  Instead of that Ubuntu system it has Partition 1 as 58 Gig of NTFS, then 25 Gig Free Space, Partition 2 as unknown and 0.0 Kb and then another 77 Gig free space.
Here are the shots

[image]

[image]

So, I don't really know what to make of it.  On one it looks like I have a lot of free space and the Disk it looks like my OS is gone.
I just want to know how to add the free space to my Linux partition.

Comment: You cannot modify *mounted* partitions, including the partition that you are currently booted from. Boot from a LiveUSB to make partition changes.

Comment: Good suggestion, so I put in a Ubuntu 20 cd and booted. I started up the Gparted. The problem is that it is sdb8 that is filled and the unallocated space is separated from it by sdb5. I am not sure how to make sdb8 larger because it appears that you have to have free space on either side of the partition you want to enlarge. I looked into maybe moving it but I couldn't really figure out how to do that. I just want to give my linux more space. I could even eliminate that fat32, but that says it's the boot directory. I don't need the windows any more because this Ubuntu is great.

Comment: OK, since I didn't know how to move the partition to get it next to the unallocated space, I shrank the partition to the left.   Then I expanded this partition into that space I had freed up.  It wouldn't boot and I looked online to see how to fix that.  Of course, I only saw the WAYYYYY too complicated explanations.  What I tried was just to restart the computer and when it starts, Ubuntu puts a small menu on the lower right, one of them is for boot options (F11), I selected that and chose my main hard drive and it started up just fine.  Win, win, win.   And even happier with Ubuntu.